# C++ IDE along with minimal Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ide

My intention is to have a C++ integrated development environment on Linux platform without any pain or extra configuration or building binaries from source, etc..

I found that [CodeBlocks Studio](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26) has readily available RPMs for Fedora, Suse and Mandriva.

Can I arrange minimal ISOs (50-100 MB) for these distributions?

Answer (score 4):

Fedora already has CodeBlocks and other popular IDEs such as Anjuta and KDevelop included as official packages. If you need a bootable media with your favourite IDE, spin your own Live CD with a custom set of packages.

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_a_Live_CD

Answer (score 0):

> Can I arrange minimal ISOs (50-100 MB) for these distributions?

The very idea of IDEs — the more so graphical ones — goes against "minimal". I am afraid you won't be getting below 300 MB.

Comment: Then please post a download link for any of these distros that falls withing 300 MB.

Comment: http://pastebin.ca/2029712 is a openSUSE 11.3 trimmed. (Still no X server, no compilers, and most of the useful shell utilities are gone too.) But it may be startable via `ssh -Y`.